# ¿Cómo obtener tiempo de actividad de un proceso desde otra aplicación?

Tags: java, windows

quiero elaborar una app que se ejecute en segundo plano y quiero que obtenga el tiempo que permanece activa otra app en ejecución ¿alguna idea?

lo quiero intentar con un BufferedReader y asi mismo acceder al archivo que muestra los registros de cada actividad, pero no he podido encontrar información solo en Windows, si aguien conoce de este tema se los agradecería.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;


public class MiClasesita {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    try{
    
        String str_proceso = null;
        String admin = 
        System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\" + "tasklist.exe";
        Process proceso = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(admin);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(proceso.getInputStream()));
        while((str_proceso = input.readLine()) != null){
        System.out.println(str_proceso);
        }
        input.close();
    
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qué problema tienes con este código que nos muestras?

Comment: Creo que tienes que usar un servicio para eso.

Comment: @Alfabravo ese funciona solo para una pc y yo quiero hacerlo desde un dispositivo android

Comment: Ah! Fíjate que eso no lo decías en ninguna parte de la pregunta ni en la etiqueta. Piensa en [edit] y ampliar la pregunta con lo que realmente buscas.